# How to copy the full C: drive to an external disk, to copy to another machine?

Tags: windows-7, disk-cloning

Windows 7:
I need to return a loan PC and I want to copy ALL of it, to an external drive, to copy to my own machine when I get it back.

How do I copy ALL on C: to E:?

Comment: Well, do you want the E: drive to be a bootable copy of Windows?   You might run into some issues with drivers not working if you try to boot it on a computer with different hardware.   If you need a bootable clone of the C: drive, I would recommend a product called Miray HDD Clone (https://www.miray.de/download/hdclone.html) .   There is a freeware version available, but it does limit the max transfer speed to 20MB/s.   The paid versions allow much higher transfer rates.   Great tool tho, never had it fail on me and it creates exact copies of hard drives and makes them bootable.

Comment: Also, the license key might not work on different hardware?

Comment: Aye.. Just copying the data should be fine though, and her own machine should have its own install and matching CoA.

Comment: If you don't need to clone the hard drive (meaning you get to boot off the cloned disk) you can use [FastCopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) to copy all files/folders preserving folder structure to your backup drive. I prefer it over regular Windows copy + paste because it can also copy files/folders with long names or paths quite easily.

Comment: Use Windows Backup.

Answer (score 1):

You image it. Assuming you don't want to restore it, and since its a loaner, you don't want to install anything, use [disk2vhd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656415.aspx) to make an image.

Then simply copy this image over and mount it - vhd mounts are native to windows 7 and you simply need to go to "create and format hard disk partitions - > "action" -> attach vhd.

[image]

In this case I'd imaged a whole device with 2 partitions, and its mounted on a nas. It mounts up pretty quickly

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

1. Install UNetBootin.
2. Open it.
3. Write Ubuntu to a spare USB
4. Boot to the Ubuntu live CD
5. Open a terminal, and type `sudo apt-get install -y gnome-disk-utility; gnome-disk-utility`
6. After it loads, click on the hard disk you would like to backup, and then click on the gear icon, then click on "Create disk image"
7. Choose to save the backup image to your second hard drive
8. Wait for it, then shut down, and you are done.

To restore the disk image:
1. Follow steps 4-6, but click "Restore disk image"
2. Follow the instructions